# Node.js server not working all of a sudden

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It worked fine yesterday and now it's giving me this error. The API I created worked fine and all of the requests worked, now I have no idea what's wrong.

I used ng serve for my Angular app and node app.js for my API server and everything worked fine, why isn't it connecting now?

```
Running on port 4000...
(node:13096) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:13096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heiko\Documents\parkingApi\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heiko\Documents\parkingApi\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Heiko\Documents\parkingApi\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:257:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:448:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:424:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:288:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:251:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:211:10)
(node:13096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I think your mongo server is down try to restart it

Comment: Is the MongoDB server process running? The error suggests that it isn't ("MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server ...")

Comment: How do I do that? I usually ran the two commands and eveything worked fine.

Comment: usually to start mongoDB server you should type: mongod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log clearly shows that your node server is unable to connect to MongoDB. The reasons might be any. Let me list down a few possibilities.

- MongoDB Server is down. You might have to restart the same
- You node server might be behind some firewall which doesn't allow DB connection to external DBs.

You can check the connection from shell using:

`mongod "mongodb_host_url"`

Comment: I'm working on localhost and never had a problem like this before though.

Comment: Is your mongo server running on localhost ? Can you check by connecting to the DB from shell by using `mongod "mongodb_host_url"`

Comment: Yes, Angular app on :4200 and node server on :3000

Comment: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

Can't even run mongo shell :o
2018-09-10T17:35:13.895+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

cant even run mongo shell :O

Comment: Can you check whether you mongo server is running ? Are you running as windows background service ?

Comment: Ok so I did mongod- It said that waiting for connections on port 27017. Then I ran mongo and It said "connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51690" and the API seems to be working now, but all the data is missing

Comment: MongoDB was stopped under services and I started it now. Still same as before.

Comment: Yes, now I guess your server is up. Now mongo saves data in some default directory. You can set the same directory as data dir while restarting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179752/discussion-between-vizsatiz-and-heiko-piirme).